# I want to display same column twice with different values mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**select * from Teams;**

```
| team_name | team_id | 
| India     |       1 | 
| England   |       2 | 
| Germany   |       3 |
| Japan     |       4 |
```

**select * from Matches;**

```
| match_id | match_date | hometeam | awayteam | homescore | awayscore |
|        1 | 2014-06-24 |        1 |        2 |         3 |         0 |
|        2 | 2014-06-25 |        3 |        4 |         0 |         2 |
```

Matches-table `hometeam` and `awayteam` are foreign keys for Teams-table `team_id`

---

I want a select that displays the `homescore` and `awayscore` along with `team_names`

Comment: clarify your question, it's not clean

Comment: I think you need to think better at your db. It's better to have a column called points on Teams table than summing it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a place for programmers who get stuck after trying to achieve a definite result and programmers who are happy to help such people. What have you tried? Do you have any idea about table joins?

Comment: What would the desired result actually look like?

Comment: SELECT th.team_name, m.homescore, ta.team_name, m.awayscore FROM Matches m  INNER JOIN Teams th ON m.hometeam = th.team_id INNER JOIN Teams ta ON m.awayteam = ta.team_id and match_id=1;;
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| team_name | homescore | team_name | awayscore |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| India     |         3 | England   |         0 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+

Answer (score 3):

You have to join matches table with teams table like this:

```
SELECT th.team_name as team_home, m.homescore, ta.team_name as team_away, m.awayscore
FROM matches m 
INNER JOIN teams th ON m.hometeam = th.team_id
INNER JOIN teams ta ON m.awayteam = ta.team_id
```

Here is [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cb0a/2)

Answer (score 0):

Another one, with entire match data in one select...

```
select 
  m.*, 
  home.team_name as hometeam_name, 
  away.team_name as awayteam_name
from 
  matches m,
  teams home,
  teams away
where
  home.team_id = m.hometeam
  and
  away.team_id = m.awayteam
;
```

see **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf8cd3/1)**